# Finding values of prime such that 4+product of primes is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> Let$ p_1, p_2, p_3$ be primes with $p_2 \neq p_3$, such that $4 + p_1p_2$ and $4 + p_1p_3$
> are perfect squares. Find all possible values of$ p_1, p_2, p_3$.
>
> [Source: ISI Bmath 2017 UGB](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Eadmission/IsiAdmission/PreviousQuestion/BStat-BMath-UGB-2017.pdf)

### My approach:

Assume $p_2>p_3$ and let $4+p_1p_2=m^2$ and $4+p_1p_3=k_2$  $$ \implies m^2−4=(m−2)
(m+2)=p_1p_2$$ and,
$$ k^2−4=(k−2)(k+2)=p_1p_3$$

-> $p_1=m−2$ or $m+2$ and $p_1=k−2$ or $k+2$.

If $p_1=m−2$ then $p_2=m+2$. Then if $p_1=k−2$ then $k=m$ and $p_2=p_3$ which is impossible. And if $p_1=k+2$ then $p_3=k−2<p_1<p_2$ a contradiction.

Hence, $p_1=m+2$ and $p_2=m−2$. If $p_1=k+2$ we get $m=k$ and $p_2=p_3$ so $p_1=k−2$ and $p_3=k+2$.

$$ \implies p_3=p_1+4=p_2+8$$

If $p_2=2$ then $p_1,p_3$ are even which is impossible.

I am stuck now.

Comment: Come on. Dolars!

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax. See [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).
Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers.

Comment: I've edited your post so it is type set. For the future, please typeset your question. The basics of mathjax are not very hard to learn. You will see the edit once it is peer reviewed.

Comment: I can't learn mathjax atleast not now once I'm free I will definitely learn it.

Comment: @AnmolBhullar You edit changed the meaning of the question.  It should be $k^2$ instead of $k_2$. Idem for $m$.

Comment: Ah, that's my bad. I should have double checked. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Show that $p_3=p_1+4=p_2+8$ implies that one of $p_1,p_2,p_3$ is divisible by 3.